# Datos entre métodos de controladores

Tags: c#

¿Se pueden mandar datos entre los diferentes métodos que tiene un controlador?

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(string iDocFacOpInterna)
        {
            rFEGDGen rFEGDGen = new rFEGDGen();

            rFEGDGen.iDoc = iDocFacOpInterna;

            return RedirectToAction("ViewOpInterna", new { rFEGDGen });
        }
```

El `iDocFacOpInterna` lo recibo de una vista y lo añado a una propiedad de ese modelo.

**Ejm:** `iDoc = "01"`

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult ViewOpInterna(rFEGDGen data)
        {                 
            return View();
        }
```

Luego acá intento recibir ese modelo para usarlo en este metodo pero la propiedad con el dato que llene arriba llega `null`.

**Ejm:** `iDoc = null`

Es primera vez que intento hacer eso y no sé si se puede o lo estoy haciendo mal.

***Vista***

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Index">
   <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="iDocFacOpInterna" value="01" id="checkOperacionInterna">                   
         <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
             Factura de Operación interna
         </label>
   </div>
   <button type="submit">...</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Como estas llamando a este metodo ViewOpInterna (desde la vista)

Comment: Agregue el html lo envio asi, el dato llega al controller lo que no me funciona es mandarlo al otro metodo.

Comment: Segun yo cuando usas [HttpGet] no puedes pasar un objeto tendrias que pasar solo el id  public IActionResult ViewOpInterna(string iDoc) y mandarlo asi return RedirectToAction("ViewOpInterna", new { iDoc = rFEGDGen.iDoc });

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597863/passing-object-in-redirecttoaction

Comment: Le hechare un vistazo, gracias

Comment: Puedes hacer `return ViewOpInterna(rFEGDGen)` o `return View("ViewOpInterna",rFEGDGen)`